# Subgroups order $p$ in a non-cyclic abelian finite p-group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Is it true that if $G$ is a finite abelian non-cyclic $p$-group then a subgroup of order $p$ cannot be unique? How can I prove it if the sentence is correct? 
Excuse me for the question, but I've some problem with the structure of finite p-group! Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Are you familiar with the classification of finite abelian groups?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft sorry, not very much :( I know that I can decompose an abelian finite group in the direct sum of its $p$-component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a finite abelian group $G$ is non-cyclic, it is the direct sum of more than one cyclic $p$-groups, by the *Fundamental theorem on finite abelian groups*. Each of these factors has an element of order $p$, which generates a subgroup of order $p$ in $G$, and these subgroups are distinct since their generators are.